# How can logback be configured to log at INFO level from Bootstrap on Grails 3.x?

Tags: grails, logback, grails-3.3

I'm migrating an app frm Grails 2.5.6 to Grails 3.3.9 and I'm having trouble making the logs from the Bootstrap.groovy work, I need to do a log.info "xxxx" for stuff that gets created in the init, but can't find one single example online about how that is done.

Comment: Have you tried adding `logger("my.package.BootStrap", INFO)` to your `logback.groovy`?

Comment: It worked! so simple, sad it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Logbacks groovy config is quite well documented https://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html

Comment: logback is well documented, not how Grails uses it, this is about Grails not logback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Bootstrap` is just a regular class.  So it can be handled like any other class for logging purposes.  Add a logger in your `logback.groovy`:

```
logger("my.package.BootStrap", INFO) // adjust package
```